# SDL2 How to position a window on a second monitor?

Tags: c++, window, sdl, sdl-2, monitor

I am using `SDL_SetWindowPosition` to position my window. Can I use this function to position my window on another monitor?

**UPDATE**

Using `SDL_GetDisplayBounds` will not return the correct monitor positions when the text size is changed in Windows 10. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for raising this. I was wondering why scaling was completely wrong on my side while using SDL but it turned out it was because of Windows 125% scaling. Saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 18):

SDL2 uses a global screen space coordinate system. Each display device has its own bounds inside this coordinate space. The following example places a window on a second display device:

```cpp
// enumerate displays
int displays = SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays();
assert( displays > 1 );  // assume we have secondary monitor

// get display bounds for all displays
vector< SDL_Rect > displayBounds;
for( int i = 0; i < displays; i++ ) {
    displayBounds.push_back( SDL_Rect() );
    SDL_GetDisplayBounds( i, &displayBounds.back() );
}

// window of dimensions 500 * 500 offset 100 pixels on secondary monitor
int x = displayBounds[ 1 ].x + 100;
int y = displayBounds[ 1 ].y + 100;
int w = 500;
int h = 500;

// so now x and y are on secondary display
SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow( "title", x, y, w, h, FLAGS... );
```

Looking at the definition of `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED` in `SDL_video.h` we see it is defined as

```cpp
#define SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY(0)
```

so we could also use the macro `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY( n )` where `n` is the display index.

**Update for Windows 10 - DPI scaling issue**

It seems like there is indeed a bug with SDL2 and changing the DPI scale in Windows (i.e. text scale).

Here are two bug reports relevant to the problem. They are both still apparently unresolved.

https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3433

https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2713

**Potential Solution**

I am sure that the OP could use the WIN32 api to determine the dpi scale, for `scale != 100%`, and then correct the bounds by that.

Comment: I'd like to comment on the original question to answer your question, but I do not yet have the privilege. My guess is changing the **text scale** in Windows 10 affects the screen coordinate with SDL in some way.

I had a different but related problem, until I figured out how to use SDL2 with my Mac's Retina display. (Retina uses scaling).

I suggest you try the following experiment: Output the display bounds, and check if they change, when you change the text scale setting, under Windows 10.

Comment: It could possibly be a bug with SDL2. Have you searched for others having the same experience, on Windows 10?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, all screen positions will be multiplied by 1.25 as a result of 125% text scale.

Comment: For the Win 10 scaling issue see this great article: https://nlguillemot.wordpress.com/2016/12/11/high-dpi-rendering/
If you make your app dpi aware (by using manifest or winapi's `SetProcessDpiAwareness`) `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY` will just work fine! ;)

Answer (score 2):

**DPI scaling issue** ("will not return the correct monitor positions when the text size is changed")

It's a known issue with SDL2 (I encountered it in those versions: 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, probably the older versions have this issue as well).

**Solutions:**

1) Use manifest file and set there:

```
<dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
```

(you need to include the manifest file to your app distribution)

2) Try SetProcessDPIAware().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SetWindowPosition, if you know the boundaries of the second monitor.
You can use the function SDL_GetDisplayBounds(int displayIndex,SDL_Rect* rect) to get them.