# Set SDL2 Window to specific display

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have two displays connected to my computer. When I move a window from SDL2 to my second display and the code calls the `SDL_SetWindowPosition` function, the window automatically moves to my first display. 
Is there a way to prevent this or move the window back to the display it was earlier?

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745492/sdl2-how-to-position-a-window-on-a-second-monitor).

Comment: @denormal Well sort of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the important thing is to set the window position to `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY(n)`
n specifies which window should be used.